# Android Samsung video EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT 600K Max MMS

Tags: android

why i can't control the size of the video in Samsung GalaxyS, it always record in hi resolution on other devices it work well

code example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE); 
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, UiConstants.MAX_MMS_SIZE);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_VIDEO); 
                            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 16):

This will work...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,10); //10 sec
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT,12582912L); //12*1024*1024=12MiB
startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_VIDEO); 
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

'L' is important.. It worked in my samsung phones

Comment: why 1048* 1048 and not 1024 * 1024?

Answer (score 1):

Android OEMs like Samsung can (and often do) modify the camera app to work with the cameras on their devices.

So, the most likely reason your code is not working is because Samsung's version of the default camera application either does not support low-res video capture, or it doesn't understand/process the MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT correctly.

I suggest building a compatibility function that checks the final size of the video to de-rez and clip to your MMS size limit.

Edit: Just tried MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT on a couple of devices (including a Samsung and Motorola OG Droid) and could not get it to work. MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT worked fine, however.

Comment: then how are we supposed to limit it on samsung devices?

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT,"1048576"); //1048576=(1*1024*1024)
```

I had to  pass it as a string to limit image size